# Реестр Windows на C++ в WindowsForms

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, c++-cli

Создаю WinForm'у. В main.cpp пишу:

```
include Windows.h
include WinReg.h
include string
```

В main():

```
HKEY hKey;

string regData;

DWORD buffersize = 1024;

char *lpData = new char[buffersize];

bool b = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\abc" , 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
```

Вылазит ошибка

> error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000673) "extern "C" long **cdecl
>   RegOpenKeyExA(struct HKEY** *,char const *,unsigned long,unsigned
>   long,struct HKEY__ * *)"
>   (?RegOpenKeyExA@@$$J0YAJPEAUHKEY__@@PEBDKKPEAPEAU1@@Z) referenced in
>   function "int __clrcall main(cli::array^)"
>   (?main@@$$HYMHP$01EAPE$AAVString@System@@@Z)

Выходит, что линковщик не видит тело `RegOpenKeyExA`. Почему? Я же подключил Windows.h и WinReg.h.

Comment: `Windows.h` и `WinReg.h` ничего не значат. Библиотека `advapi32.lib` в настройках линкера подключена или нет?

Comment: Подключил. Не помогло.

Comment: "Не бывает." (с) Кстати, я смотрю у вас CLI, а не С++.

Comment: Что "не бывает"? Не понял...

Comment: В сообщении линкера значится `int __clrcall main(cli::array^)`. Это не С++.

Comment: Да, да. А как починить? Мне нужно к реестру доступ получить.

Comment: Это классно, но я попробовал у себя - и все прекрасно линкуется с `advapi32.lib`. А что еще у вас там сделано неправильно - отсюда не видно.

Comment: А можете описать свои действия? Может быть я что-то неправильно делаю.

Comment: Я просто взял голый консольный Visual Studio С++ проект, проверил, что во входе линкера указана `advapi32.lib`, после чего скопировал ваш код в `main`. Все прекрасно скомпилировалось.

Comment: А если брать не голый, а приложение Windows Forms? И без advapi32.libне работает? Да, и у меня 64-битное приложение. Может advapi64.lib?

Comment: Попробовал создать Windows Forms приложение, но что-то там все по-другому. Видать что-то не то создал. Я в Windows Forms не шарю.

Comment: Если используете C++/Cli и WinForms, то смотрите класс [RegistryKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=vs.110).aspx). А если нужен нативный c++, то не используйте WinForms.